# Get the coordinates of the toggle button of the switch widget

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using this to get the x & y coordinates of the switch:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    mySwitch.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
}
```

This gives the x and y of the whole switch. How do I get the coordinates of the toggle button on the right hand side?

[image]

The whole switch is the yellow rectangle, but I'm trying to get the x, y of the toggle button that's circled with red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
int [] location = new int [2];
Switch sw = findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
sw.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int buttonX = location[0] + sw.getWidth() - sw.getPaddingRight() - (getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.switch_width))/2;
int buttonY = location[1] + (sw.getHeight()/2);
```

The default width of the toggle button seems to be approximately **50dp**. `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.switch_width)` was used so that we get the width in pixels based on the resolution of the screen.

> Inside res > values > dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="switch_width">50dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addition.

Just get the width and height of the View and add the width to the x and add the height to the y.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't give the exact x,y positions of the toggle button. After adding the width and subtracting the right padding, I'm getting the x,y of the right side of the toggle button. But I need the dead center x,y, of the button.

Comment: If you use padding, then you'll have to consider the use of subtraction too after getting the padding from `getPaddingRight()`.

Comment: I edited my previous comment and saw your answer only after the edit. I need the x, y of the center of the button.

Comment: If you're trying to get the center of the button, then you'll need division too. `x + (width / 2)`. The same is needed for the height. If your padding is only on one side of the view, you'll have to include the subtraction too for the padding.

Comment: I'm doing `x + switch.getWidth() - switch.getPaddingRight()` which almost works - it gives the location of the right limit of the toggle button. The toggle button is not on the center but is located on the right. If only I can get the width of the toggle button I can divide it by 2 and subtract from the calculation.

Comment: Have you tried `x + ((switch.getWidth() - switch.getPaddingRight()) / 2)`? But if it's the padding that's messing you up, does the layout you're using allow for margins instead of just padding? Padding affects the View itself, whereas Margins is how the layout affects the View. So if your layout allows the use of Margins, your switch.getWidth() will be the actual width of the toggle button.

Comment: I've edited the question and added an image to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I've looked at your image, and you could try `x + switch.getWidth() - switch.getPaddingRight() - (switch.getSwitchMinWidth() / 2)`. An alternative, since you have the rare requirement of needing the particular center of only the Switch, is to not use the Text field provided by the Switch. Instead, create your own TextView and place it next to the Switch where your image shows. Then in your code, use `switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` to toggle the text in the TextView you created. This way, the `switch.getWidth()` will be the proper width of just the Switch itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Have posted the answer.